# How to place elements one below another in constraint layout whose parent is scroll view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**What I am having:**

I am having 4 widgets, placed inside a constraint layout, whose parent is a scroll view

---

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to display widgets one below another

---

**What is happening:**

Widgets are placed one above another

---

**MyLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNameId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/str_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPwdId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/str_password"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNameId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChangePwdId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_change_password"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/edtPwdId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmitId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_submit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtChangePwdId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` instead of `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf`
try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNameId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/str_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPwdId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/str_password"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNameId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtChangePwdId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_change_password"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtPwdId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmitId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_submit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtChangePwdId"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: exactly , i was thinking why somebody with that much points can make that mistake

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan ... Using Constraint layout for the first time. Everyone learns from beginning :)

Comment: @Devrath ohh ok , no problem